# How to check the GATEWAY of the IP section in the VM of VMware workstation ?

Tags: networking, ip, gateway

In my remote Windows Server, I use VMware workstation created a VM, and I config a ip manually(the ip is 10.10.0.8), and the host machine(Windows Server) ip is `10.10.0.1`:

[image]

How to check the gateway of the network segment？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMD command is as follows.

```
ipconfig /all
```

Comment: If I use the `ipconfig /all` check the ip information, if the default gateway is empty, does it means there is no gateway for the `10.10.0.0/24` ?

Comment: @aircraft  Your assumption is correct.  No gateway for the 10.10.2.1/24 network.

Comment: @DaveM how can i set the gateway for it?

Comment: You need to use bridged networking or add an adapter on the host machine network  Check this out  https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html